# How to call a protocol from an extension before changing screens

Tags: swift

I need to get a value from an extension before i click on a button that goes to another screen, how can i do that?

This is the IBAction inside viewController. When i click it makes a request to an API then send a value to global variable on the second screen:

```
@IBAction func enter(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if let login = loginTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {
            loginManager.performLoginRequest(login, password)
            resultsViewController.receivedToken = token
            navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }

extension LoginViewController: LoginManagerDelegate {
    
    func didUpdateLogin(with login: LoginModel) -> (Bool, String) {
        success = login.success
        token = login.token
        
        return (success, token)
    }
}
```

Manager:

```
import Foundation

protocol LoginManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateLogin(with login: LoginModel) -> (Bool, String)
}

struct LoginManager {
    
    var delegate: LoginManagerDelegate?
    
    func performLoginRequest(_ login: String, _ password: String) {

        let url = URL(string: "https://private-anon-1a0df64d9c-ibmfc.apiary-mock.com/login")!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpBody = """
        {\n  "username": "\(login)",\n  "password": "\(password)"\n}
        """.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
          if let response = response {
            print(response)

            if let data = data, let body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(body)
                if let login = self.parseJSON(loginData: data) {
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateLogin(with: login)
                }
            }
          } else {
            print(error ?? "Unknown error")
          }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func parseJSON(loginData: Data) -> LoginModel? {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(LoginData.self, from: loginData)
            
            let success = decodedData.success
            let token = decodedData.data.token
            
            let login = LoginModel(success: success, token: token)
            
            return login
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, this extension is just being called **after** i click the button. This way `resultsViewController.receivedToken` is not getting the value from `token`.
So, how can i call `didUpdateLogin` (to pass it values to `success` and `token`) before clicking on the `IBAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe reason for this behaviour is the background thread you are using:

(1) You call `loginManager.performLoginRequest(login, password)` which then starts a background thread to actually work on that request.
(2) In the meantime your code continues to run, executing `resultsViewController.receivedToken = token`.
(3) Since (1) is not done yet, your `token` is still `nil` (or an old `token`).

One of many possible solutions:
Add a block to the parameters of `performLoginRequest` in which you call

```
resultsViewController.receivedToken = token
navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsViewController, animated: true)
```

This way you make sure that code is only called after(!) the login was successful because you wait for it. In the meantime you could show a loading spinner or something similar. Login is a task where a user simply has to wait, there is usually (depending on the app) no way around it.

The code could look something like this in the end:

```
loginManager.performLoginRequest(login, password) {
  resultsViewController.receivedToken = token
  navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsViewController, animated: true)
}
```

whereas your `LoginManager` would have a method like

```
func performLoginRequest(_ login: String,
   _ password: String,
   completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

which is then used later in your `Dispatch`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let loginVC = LoginViewController()
  loginVC.didUpdateLogin(login: login)
  completion()
}
```

Comment: sorry i did not posted my manager, this is the code:

Comment: @virtu Updated my answer accordingly. My guess was right, details in the answer. Also provided one possible solution.

Comment: Sorry the delay @Dominic Frei, i made a mistake while  providing you code details. Actually, the default code does not has a `DispatchQueue.main.async`block. It ends on `self.delegate?.didUpdateLogin(with: login)` then jump to the `else` code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion anyway and got some problems while including `completion()` parameter. On `LoginViewController`file i added a block to `performLoginRequest` but problem is on `LoginManager` file. I added `completion: () -> Void`as a parammter on `performLoginRequest` but it is not accepting on `data`block saying "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'".

Comment: I edited again with the original code. `DispatchQueue.main.async`block was added on another file that i was creating a part trying to resolve this whole problem.

Comment: @virtu To resolve "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion" your need to mark this block as "@escaping" as stated in the description of the error. :) That's actually missing in my answer. I'm gonna edit it in.

Comment: Thanks, i re-added the 'DispatchQueue' block and added '@escaping', now it works :)